# continue the line drawing on dotnet highchart

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm creating a dotnet high chart by using the code:

```
object[,] data1 = new object[Dt.Rows.Count, 2];
for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    data1[i, 0] = Dt.Rows[i]["IncDate"];
    data1[i, 1] = Dt.Rows[i]["IncCost"];
}

object[,] data2 = new object[Dt2.Rows.Count, 2];
for (int i = 0; i < Dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    data2[i, 0] = Dt2.Rows[i]["ExpDate"];
    data2[i, 1] = Dt2.Rows[i]["ExpCost"];
}

Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("graph")

    .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Money Analysis" })
    .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Type = AxisTypes.Datetime })
    .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Amount (£)" } })
    .SetSeries(new[]
        {
        new Series { Name = "Incomings", Color = Color.LimeGreen, Data = new Data(data1) },
        new Series { Name = "Expenditures", Color = Color.Red, Data = new Data(data2) }
    })
```

which outputs:
[image: DotNet highchart]
I was wondering how I'm able to make the red line continue along the current cost until the end of the graph (the last date for the incoming.) And also do the same for the green line if the expenditures have a later date than the last incomings date. Hopefully people know what I mean. Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to calculate these data points yourself and provide them as part of the data array(s).

Comment: so there is no way to do it dynamically?

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to just hold the last value, and draw the line until the end? Or you want it to continue the established slope until the end? Either way, you still need to write that code yourself, but one is easier than the other

Comment: yes just hold the last value and draw the line until the end

Comment: Ok, I mis-read it as the other option. check answer below for working example

Answer (score 3):

So, no - the chart won't do that for you automatically, but we can do it ourselves easy enough.

1) retrieve the final y value of your data

2) retrieve the final x value that you want it to extend until

3) add a new point to the data with those x and y values.

**Example function:**

```
function extendData(series, axis) {
    var ext = axis.getExtremes();
    var x   = ext.dataMax;
    var y   = series.data[series.data.length -1].y;
    series.addPoint({'x':x, 'y':y, marker: { enabled: true }});
  }
```

**Working example:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/omtugbvo/

And just to show an example using any number of series:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/omtugbvo/3/

**Example image:**

[image: extend line]

Comment: Thank you for this. Although I'm not sure how to implement it to my own highchart

Comment: Thanks! Just to add - for an area chart it's `var y   = series.data[series.data.length - 1]; series.addPoint([x, y.low, y.high]);`